# Отправка файла на почту из кеша

Tags: php

```
$fp = fopen($file_name, "rb");
$code_file1 = chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($fp, filesize($path))));
```

Если ссылка на файл `$file_name` указывает на путь файла на сервере, то файл успешно отправляется.

Однако, если файл  отправляю с html-формы, приходит 15-байтовый битый файл.

```
$file_name=$_FILES["attach1"]["name"];
```

Как отправлять именно с кеша?

Comment: вы наверняка хотели использовать $file_name вместо $path

Comment: приведите заодно, пожалуйста, и фрагмент кода, отправляющий почту. чтобы было видно, какими функциями/классами вы оперируете.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `tmp_name` вместо name:

```
$file_name=$_FILES["attach1"]["tmp_name"];
```

`tmp_name` - полный путь к временному файлу

`name` - имя исходного загружаемого файла, которому к тому же не рекомендуется доверять и всегда требуется валидация в случае использования.

См. также http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php